# Displaying a table in EMBED using tabulate discord.py

Tags: python, mysql, discord.py, embed, tabulate

I want to show table with aligned columns but having issue with spaces, I am using tabulate module for displaying table

my code:(ignore the 3rd line of script)

```
cur = await self.bot.db.execute("SELECT inviter_name, normal, bonus, leaves, fake FROM totals WHERE guild_id = ?",(ctx.guild.id,))
res = await cur.fetchall()
rows=len(res)
t=tabulate(res)
emb=discord.Embed(title=f"Invite Leaderboard for {member.guild.name}", description=f"`{t}`", color=0xFFA500)
emb.set_thumbnail(url=member.guild.icon.url)
await ctx.send(embed=emb)
```

Output: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3e3Pa.png)

desired Output: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVMWm.png)

MySQL table(not the actual table, just for reference that it looks like this): [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OoZS.png)

I thought that if any spaces in names causing issue so for that I have searched over the internet to strip list having multiple tuples but haven't found any valuable lead yet.

I just wanna know if the length of the names causing spaces or if there anything wrong I am doing, if so then where

I don't know if this is of any help:
length of first name is 14 and second name is 8
and I am using varchar datatype for names

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found was with the library "table2ascII", however it does not have wrapping (multiline) like tabulate, so if your column size is too big it won't fit in Embed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).